# Row level timestamp information in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, database-design, google-bigquery, schema

I am working on a table in BigQuery. The table is already populated with data. I want to know if the BigQuery holds any kind of row level information from where I can know the row inserted or modified datetime?

Comment: I don't think such metadata is readily available. As a side comment, from the best of my understanding, a record in a BigQuery table cannot be modified - it can be deleted, and a new one can be created - by doing those 2 operations a 'modification' is emulated.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? Is your question about finding the last modified date of a table?

Comment: Please provide more details to help us understand the output you are trying to obtain.

Comment: @al-dann record modification *is* supported in BigQuery. UPDATE is a valid DML statement in BigQuery.

Comment: just again - record modification is emulated in BigQuery. The data in BigQuery is immutable. In order to emulate the standard UPDATE operator "an atomic combination of an INSERT and a DELETE operations" happens. See, for example, the page 225 of the "Google BigQuery The Definitive Guide" [2020] by Lakshmanan and Tigani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery provides no such metadata. You would have to create such fields and populate them yourself.